# Create member variable with closure in its constructor

Tags: swift, closures

I'm having the following code in my class:

```
    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    init() {
        authenticationContext = AuthenticationContext()
        synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext()

        employeesCoordinator = EmployeesCoordinator()

        serverErrorObserver =
            NotificationObserver(notification: serverErrorNotification,
                                 block: handleServerError) // <- Error
    }

    // MARK: - Listeners

    private let serverErrorObserver: NotificationObserver!

    private lazy var handleServerError: NSError -> () = {
        [unowned self] (error) in
        // Currently means that the token is expired, so remove stored instance
        self.handleAuthorizationDidExpired()
    }
```

It looks legit, but I'm getting the following complier error:

> Use of 'self' in property access 'handleServerError' before all stored
>   properties are initialized

If it would help, this is the source behind **NotificationObserver**:

```
class ValueWrapper<T> {
    let value: T
    init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }
}

//  Notification

struct Notification<A> {
    let name: String
}

// Global Functions

func publish<A>(note: Notification<A>, value: A) {
    let userInfo = ["value": ValueWrapper(value)]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(note.name, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}

// 

class NotificationObserver {

    let observer: NSObjectProtocol

    init<A>(notification: Notification<A>, block aBlock: A -> ()) {
        observer = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(notification.name, object: nil, queue: nil) { note in
            let wrapper = note.userInfo?["value"] as? ValueWrapper<A>
            if let value = wrapper?.value {
                aBlock(value)
            } else {
                assert(false, "Couldn't understand user info")
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(observer)
    }

}

// Global variables

let serverErrorNotification: Notification<NSError> = Notification(name: "ServerErrorNotification")
let synchronizationDidCompleteNotification: Notification<Int> = Notification(name: "SynchronizationDidCompleteNotification")
let authorizationDidCompleteNotification: Notification<Authorization> = Notification(name: "SynchronizationDidCompleteNotification")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call self until you have properly initialized the object using super.init()

if you have un-initialized **let** variables they should initialize before super.init() call.
so doing so you cannot call to self - closure calls to self

so you have to change **let** to **var**, then call super.init() before assigning closure

```
private let serverErrorObserver: NotificationObserver!
```

to

```
private var serverErrorObserver: NotificationObserver!
```

eg.

```
init() {
 super.init()
    authenticationContext = AuthenticationContext()
    synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext()

    employeesCoordinator = EmployeesCoordinator()

    serverErrorObserver =
        NotificationObserver(notification: serverErrorNotification,
                             block: handleServerError) // <- Error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are accessing `self` in the `init()` in the following line:

`self.handleAuthorizationDidExpired()`

You can't do it until all of the stored properties are initialised. And the only property, which is not initialised yet in your case, is `serverErrorObserver`.

In order to fix it easily, you can mark this property in the following way:

`private(set) var serverErrorObserver: NotificationObserver?`

By marking it optional you tell the compiler that this property doesn't need to be initialised when the object is created.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is awesome. I wish I could mark both answers as accepted, however I accepted @RJE's answer, because he was the first to answer.